# accessing an element in a numpy matrix using a list (python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 10x10 numpy matrix and I have a list containing indices of elements I want to query.

`matrix = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)`

`indices = [[2,3], [3,4]]`

the issue I'm facing is, what I actually want is the element `matrix[2,3]` but `matrix[indices[0]]` gives a different output because the latter actually means `matrix[[2,3]]`. the output is 2 different rows.

How do I get around this problem?

Comment: `arr[ [2,3], [3,4] ]` or `indices=([2,3], [3,4])` and `arr[indices]`.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution.

storing the indices as tuples inside of a list works

`indices = [(2,3), (3,4)]` and then `matrix[indices[0]]` gives the desired output